# Using CMake, how do I identify the dependant of a target

Tags: cmake

I have a library which builds as multiple flavours. These different flavours (combinations of GUI/CLI and shared/static) were incomplete and inconsistently named. In fixing this, the original target names are no longer used.

The library is brought in as an external to many other projects. In order to avoid upsetting people and confusing the hell out of them I have created "dummy" targets using the original names that output a useful error message. I have also set the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` property so that these dummy targets will only get built if they are explicitly used somewhere.

```
add_library(Utilities STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(Utilities PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR}/Utilities.warning"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc"
    EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE
)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR}/Utilities.warning"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E cmake_echo_color --red "The 'Utilities' target has been replaced by 'Utilities_shared'. Please update your CMakeLists.txt."
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E false
)
add_custom_target(Utilities_fail DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR}/Utilities.warning")
add_dependencies(Utilities Utilities_fail)
```

So far so good, it all works well...except that when one of these dummy targets is hit, I don't know where it is being included from. Our projects include many libraries, some of which also use this specific library. I would like to update the error message that is printed to identify *which* CMakeLists.txt needs to be updated. E.g.:

```
The 'Utilities' target has been replaced by 'Utilities_shared'. Please update the 'other_library' CMakeLists.txt.
```

or even:

```
The 'Utilities' target has been replaced by 'Utilities_shared'. Please update /home/Me/Work/MyProject/libs/OtherLib/CMakeLists.txt.
```

Is there a CMake generator expression, or some other way, that I can identify the "ancestor" target that this target is a dependency of? If it is included in multiple places I only really care about the "first" one.

Comment: This is rather new and I've never used it, but it could be what you're looking for: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/DEPRECATION.html If this does not work for you'll probably need to require the users to modify their code. E.g. a macro for linking your lib to be used instead of `target_link_libraries` could link the real names instead of  the ones used and print a warning. You could also go with config scripts to be used with `find_package` that check for deprecated names...

Comment: Requiring the users to modify their code is a bit awkward. The whole purpose is already to flag to the users which part of their code to modify.

That flag looks a possibility, but the description is VERY thin. It would take a lot of experimentation.